# How can I write a Perl subroutine that works both as a normal subroutine or a class method?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a function that is mostly static in nature.  I want to plug it into Template Toolkit, which passes along the class name.  In essential, it is doing

```
ClassName->function( $args.. )
```

but I want it to do something like

```
ClassName::function( $args.. )
```

inside

```
sub function {
}
```

what is the proper way to handle both cases?

Comment: Why do you want to do something like ClassName::function( $args.. )?

Comment: It's a static/helper method that doesn't really depend on the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there isn't. a `sub` is either written to be called as a method or it isn't.

See how [File::Spec::Functions](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SMUELLER/PathTools-3.30/lib/File/Spec/Functions.pm) handles this situation by prepending the package name to the argument list.

Now, ***in a very specific, limited case***, you can do:

```
shift if $_[0] eq __PACKAGE__;
```

as the first line in your sub to discard the first argument when the `sub` is called as a class method.

Comment: +1. This becomes safer if each of your functions takes a fixed number of arguments, in which case you can decide whether OO call syntax was used based on whether there is 1 more parameter than expected. (As it stands, calling "ClassName::function('ClassName');" will trigger a false positive.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a safer version that combines [Sinan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038975/perl-function-with-or-without-class/1039050#1039050) and [Alan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038975/perl-function-with-or-without-class/1039047#1039047) answers, and also:

- Handles the possibility that the method is called from a derived object
- Won't misinterpret `ClassName::function("ClassName")` as a method call

The code:

```
if (@_ == $nArgsExpectedForThisFunc + 1) {
    $_[0] eq __PACKAGE__ || UNIVERSAL::isa($_[0], __PACKAGE__) || die;
    shift;
}
```

This requires that you know the number of arguments to expect; if you don't, but your first argument can be differentiated from the possible allowable values that might be sent when it is called as a method (e.g. if your first argument must be an arrayref), the same general principle can still be applied.

Comment: +1 Nice combo but I also like Michael Carman's wrapper idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038975/perl-function-with-or-without-class/1039085#1039085

Answer (score 4):

Template Toolkit expects it's plugins to use OO, so there's no way around providing that interface. If you also want a functional interface you have a couple of options.

Perl doesn't really distinguish between a function and a method. The main difference is that the method invocation syntax implicitly includes the object reference (or class name, depending on how it was invoked) as the first argument. You can use function call syntax and provide the referent manually:

```
ClassName::function('ClassName', @args);
```

but that's messy. The cleaner solution would be to split it into two subs with one a wrapper for the other. e.g.

```
package ClassName;

sub function {
    # do something
}

sub method {
    my $class = shift;
    function(@_);
}
```

The function could be a wrapper around the method as well. As Sinan alluded to, File::Spec does this by creating two modules: one with the OO interface and one with a functional interface.

Comment: Or let Perl do the wrapping for you: "package ClassName::Functional; sub AUTOLOAD { no strict refs; ClassName->$AUTOLOAD(@_); }"

Comment: @j_random_hacker: no strict refs should be no strict "refs" or it fails under strict subs :)  except that it isn't needed because ->$method is allowed under strict refs.  And $AUTOLOAD is fully qualified, so you need our $AUTOLOAD=~s/.*:://; or you get infinite recursion.

Comment: @ysth: Thanks! (So many bugs in so little code, wow...) Any idea why "->$method" is allowed without strict 'refs'? Just another arbitrary Perl inconsistency?

Comment: strict refs is there to keep people from accidentally using symbolic refs; if $method doesn't have a package it isn't a reference of any kind, and if it does have a package, it's pretty clearly intentional.  goto &$funcref is exempted too.